# C# : IndexOf storing 2 values at a time

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to break a single string into 3 strings but i am having a problem using `indexOf`
when I input a string like for e.g `15,M,true i-e` use 2 commas in the input

```
Console.Write("Enter Your Pyrimid Slot Number ; Block Number ; whether or not the block should be lit or not ?");
String pyrimidSLOT = Console.ReadLine();
int commaNUMBER = pyrimidSLOT.IndexOf(",");
String pyrimidSLOTNUMBER = pyrimidSLOT.Substring(0, commaNUMBER);
Console.WriteLine("Your Block Number is : " + pyrimidSLOTNUMBER);
```

The code works fine till here

```
string blockNUMBER = pyrimidSLOT.Substring(commaNUMBER + 1, commaNUMBER +1 );
Console.WriteLine("YOUR bLOCK nUMBER IS : " + blockNUMBER);
```

But when i try to separate the "Block Number" from the input string using the above code it output 
`YOUR bLOCK nUMBER IS : M,t` but works fine when i change the code to

```
string blockNUMBER = pyrimidSLOT.Substring(commaNUMBER + 1, commaNUMBER -1 );
```

why is it not storing the value of just the first index ? `commaNumber + 1` is the starting index and `commaNUMBER - 1` is the ending index does that does noy make any sense ?

Comment: so the question is why is it not storing the value of just the first index ? commaNumber + 1 is the starting index and commaNUMBER is the ending index does that make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be easily done with string.Split

```
string[] parts = pyrimidSLOT.Split(',');
Console.WriteLine(parts[0]);
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);
Console.WriteLine(parts[2]);
```

instead with IndexOf, you need to split the string yourself, and remember that the second parameter of string.Substring is a `Length`, meaning that you need to pass the number of characters to extract from the starting position.

```
int firstComma = pyrimidSLOT.IndexOf(',');
string slot = pyrimidSLOT.Substring(0, firstComma);
int secondComma = pyrimidSLOT.IndexOf(",", firstComma + 1);
string block = pyrimidSLOT.Substring(firstComma + 1, secondComma - firstComma - 1);
string hi = pyrimidSLOT.Substring(secondComma +1);
Console.WriteLine(slot);
Console.WriteLine(block);
Console.WriteLine(hi);
```

Of course, this assumes that your input string contains exactly two commas separated by at least one character

Answer (score 3):

Just use the string.Split() method. E.g.:

```
string[] parts = pyramidSlot.Split(',');
Console.WriteLine("Your block number is {0}.", parts[0]);
```